# Sql Statement trying to understand join statements

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

My code is pasted here for the Sql tables and information: http://pastebin.com/GsKp4z30

what I am trying to do is:
SuperClean would like to offer a special to their customers that use coupons. Retrieve the names and
addresses for the customers using coupons on any order from September 1, 2014 through December 24,
2014.

But I keep getting 40+ lines of information and I can't seem to get a join statement to work correctly.

I was trying this but I keep getting invalid identifier.

```
SELECT
    CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME, CUSTOMER_CUSTOMER_NAME, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ADDRESS
FROM CUSTOMER
INNER JOIN
    CUSTOMER ON CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER_INVOICE.CUSTOMER_ID;
```

Comment: "What I am trying to do is: get someone to do my homework" - what join statements have you tried so far?

Comment: I was trying this but I keep getting invalid identifier. 

SELECT CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME, CUSTOMER_CUSTOMER_NAME, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ADDRESS
FROM CUSTOMER
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER
ON CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID= CUSTOMER_INVOICE.CUSTOMER_ID;

Comment: so after inner join should be a table I haven't added yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a good first attempt.

Your first problem comes from `INNER JOIN CUSTOMER` - you are already selecting from `CUSTOMER`, so why JOIN it with `CUSTOMER`? You should be joining with `CUSTOMER_INVOICE` instead:

```
SELECT
    CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ADDRESS
FROM CUSTOMER
INNER JOIN
    CUSTOMER_INVOICE ON CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER_INVOICE.CUSTOMER_ID;
```

I've also fixed the other problem with your `SELECT`, before it was this:

```
SELECT
    CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME, CUSTOMER_CUSTOMER_NAME, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ADDRESS
```

Yet there is no column or alias defined as `CUSTOMER_CUSTOMER_NAME`. So it will throw you an invalid identifier error.

This will return all of the customers with respective customer invoices - now we need to filter it down to invoices with the coupons set to `YES` using `WHERE`:

```
SELECT
    CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ADDRESS
FROM CUSTOMER
INNER JOIN
    CUSTOMER_INVOICE ON CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER_INVOICE.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE
    CUSTOMER_INVOICE.COUPON_YESNO = 'YES';
```

and now filter the result-set down further to work with the particular date range from your question. I'll let you figure this part out unless you're having difficulty understanding the `WHERE`.

Comment: Yes, I just changed it to CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME, there was a typo. OK I still need a little explanation on the join syntax, we used one table we weren't using before and that table has to go behind the inner join?

Comment: @user2989486 The typical syntax is `SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name`. The table name that follows `INNER JOIN` specifies the table to be joined to the table after `FROM`, and the condition after the `ON` clause specifies how to match up the rows between the left table (`table1`) and the right table (`table2`). Typically this is done by having one table store a foreign key to the other joined table. After you get a basic result set from all the joins, you use the `WHERE` to filter the data set based on the parameters of your problem